# GWT SafeHtmlTemplate Internationalization

Tags: gwt

I'm in the process of internationalizing my gwt app and I have several [SafeHtmlTemplate](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/client/SafeHtmlTemplates.html) that I'm using that I'm not sure how to translate. Is there a convenient way to translate these while still using the `SafeHtmlTemplate` approach? Otherwise, would I just pass in the names of the days of the week to the template and translate them using `Constants` as usual?

```
    @Template("<table>" + 
            "<tr><td>Sunday:</td>{6}</tr>" +
            "<tr><td>Monday:</td>{0}</tr>" +
            "<tr><td>Tuesday:</td>{1}</tr>" +
            "<tr><td>Wednesday:</td>{2}</tr>" +
            "<tr><td>Thursday:</td>{3}</tr>" +
            "<tr><td>Friday:</td>{4}</tr>" +
            "<tr><td>Saturday:</td>{5}</tr>" +
            "</table>")
    SafeHtml hoursHtml(SafeHtml mon, SafeHtml tue, SafeHtml wed, SafeHtml thu, SafeHtml fri, SafeHtml sat, SafeHtml sun);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's no way to use a `Constants` object inside a template like you would do with a `UiBinder` template, I'd say your approach of getting the translated strings outside the template and then passing them as parameters would be the next easier option.

Moreover, it's mentioned time and again all through GWT's `SafeHtml` documentation that the strings used to build `SafeHtml` objects must be already determined at compile time:

> [`public interface SafeHtmlTemplates`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/client/SafeHtmlTemplates.html)
>   A tag interface that facilitates **compile-time** binding of HTML templates to generate SafeHtml strings.
>
> [`public static SafeHtml fromSafeConstant(java.lang.String s)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtmlUtils.html#fromSafeConstant-java.lang.String-)
>   Returns a SafeHtml constructed from a safe string, i.e., without escaping the string.
>   Important: For this method to be able to honor the SafeHtml contract, all uses of this method must satisfy the following constraints:
>   1. The argument expression must be fully determined at **compile time**.
>   2. The value of the argument must end in "inner HTML" context and not contain incomplete HTML tags.

The use of `Constants` inside `SafeHtml` templates might interfere with this rule.
One could argue that all constants are supposedly inlined, and internationalized permutations of the code are generated at compile time already, so it should be relatively easy to overcome those restrictions when using constants inside templates; but then again, Google might have implemented it in a way that doesn't allow safe mixing of both mechanisms, hence the limitation.

So just passing the translated strings as parameters is (probably) the way to go.